# How to better design this code and logic

Tags: grails, architecture, groovy

A `Request` class has a property `colorType` which can be of different colors. Based on the type of color it is will involve handling it differently.

Here is the controller code:

```
def colorInstance = Color(params)
//validates and checks the params. Also, based on some logic sets the `colorType` property 
//to be appropriate color
if (colorInstnace.validate()) 
{
   colorService.processColor(colorInstance)
}
```

Here is the `colorService` code:

```
void processColor(Color colorInstance) { 
  if (colorInstance.colorType == "green")
      processGreen(colorInstance)
  else if (colorInstance.colorType == "red")
      processRed(colorInstance)
  ....
  ......
}

processGreen(Color colorInstance) {
  //common code
  //code specific to colortypes that are GREEN
  //more common code
}

processRed(Color colorInstance) { 
  //common code
  //code specific to colortypes that are RED
  //more common code
}
```

**Questions**

1. How can I change the code in the service so that I don't have to copy paste the code in all the `processXXX` methods?
2. How can I eliminate the `if/elseif` in the `processColor` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service class can have the below implementation. [Switch case](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Logical+Branching) in groovy can handle any value, you need not use any primitive datatype.

```
void processColor(Color colorInstance) { 
  processCommonCodeBefore(colorInstance)
  processColorSpecificCode(colorInstance)
  processCommonCodeAfter(colorInstance)      
}

processCommonCodeBefore(Color colorInstance) {
  //common code
}

processCommonCodeAfter(Color colorInstance) { 
  //common code
}

processColorSpecificCode(Color colorInstance) { 
     switch(colorInstance.colorType){
        case 'green':
            processGreen(colorInstance)
            break
        case 'blue':
            processBlue(colorInstance)
            break
        default:
            processDefault(colorInstance)
     }      
}
```

This way all the methods inside service class can be efficiently Unit tested.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier if you used integer constants instead.. e.g.

```
// you could use actual RGB too.. then red would be 0xff0000
static final int RED = 0
static final int BLUE = 1
static final int GREEN = 2
```

Then in the colorService, you could try something like this...

```
void processColor(Color colorInstance) { 
  commonMethodOne();

  switch(colorInstance.colorType){

  case RED:
     //Handle the red color
  case BLUE:
    // Handle the blue color, etc.

  }

  commonMethodTwo();
}

commonMethodOne(){
  //Here is code that gets executed regardless of Color
}

commonMethodTwo(){
  //Here is more code that gets executed regardless of Color
}
```

Comment: If he's using Groovy, he should go ahead and use type-safe enums instead of integer constants.

Answer (score 1):

Even if a answer has been accepted I want to point out an alternative solution using an `enum` for `ColorType`.

```
class Color {
    ColorType colorType
    ...
}

enum ColorType {
    blue {
        @Override void process(Color color) {
            // code for processing blue
        }
    },
    green {
        @Override void process(Color color) {
            // code for processing green
        }
    },
    red,
    yellow

    void process(Color color) {
        // used for red and yellow
    }
}
```

Like in java you can add methods to enums (like `process(Color color)`). You can also override these methods for certain enum constants. In this example the enum values `blue` and `green` override the `process(Color color)` method.

Using this approach you would be able to do this:

```
void processColor(Color colorInstance) {
     commonMethod(colorInstance)
     colorInstance.colorType.process(colorInstance)
     otherCommonMethod(colorInstance)
}
```

The problem with this example is that it creates a circular dependency between `Color` and `ColorType` which should be avoided. But depending on your implementation it might be possible to remove the `color` parameter from the `ColorType.process()` method to solve this problem.

I just wanted to point out that overriding enum methods can sometimes be a useful feature for such situations :-)

Comment: `Color` is a persistent entity represented by a grails domain class in OP's question, which should have the entities as members of the class. Therefore, `colorType` would be representing the column `COLOR_TYPE` in `COLOR` table, although your approach could be convenient for POGO classes.

Comment: Hm I don't get your point. You can reference/save enums in domain classes without problems.